# Where the accent should be when the beat is made up of different notes

Tags: theory, time-signatures

As far as I understood the difference between the various time signature is essentially where strong and soft beats are located. For example in 4/4 we have strong beat - soft beat - medium strong beat and soft beat. In 3/4 strong beat- soft beat - soft beat. In compoud time signatures the strong beat is the first of each three.

The question is, if the single beat is made up of different notes where should the accent be located?
For example:

**Case A**

[image]

**Case B**

[image]

**Case C**

[image]

*What's the general rule to determine the position of the accent?*

Comment: This is not a chicken and egg situation. The accents are there in the music *before* it's written down. Where they come is what determines *how* they get portrayed in the music. Thus, generally speaking, the first emphasised or accented beat is recognised as the first part of the bar.

Comment: "For example in 4/4 we have strong beat - soft beat - medium strong beat and soft beat."  Not always.  Perhaps not even usually.  For example, there is "middle soft strong soft," and "soft strong soft strong" in 4/4, and I don't think these are uncommon at all.

Comment: Your 6/8 example should either be in 3/4 instead or be re-beamed appropriately.

Comment: The *general rule* is that the very first sound in a bar is accented. In cases A and B that would be the 1st semi. Case C is written wrongly anyway, but the first note played is accented - in normal situations.

Comment: @Dekkadeci: As I may have mentioned. Ahem.

Comment: You have technical answer below, I want to add a comment.  Accents on 1 and 2 are typical for classical and rock, but that is not the only way it is done.   In jazz we typically accent the 2nd and 4th beats, or just the 2nd for 3/4.  And then, we move it a little ahead or behind the beat.  It creates a little extra energy and compared to the synchrony of classical music and rock, it is more conducive to interaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accents for subdivisions follow the same patterns as for time signatures. So, a subdivision of 4 would be accent like a measure of 4:

[image: quadruple division of a beat]

And a subdivision of 3 would be

[image: triple division of a beat]

All of those accents are relative to which beat in the measure contains those subdivisions.

Comment: Sometimes there are variations- it depends on the piece. For triple time it is often - strong, weakest, weak etc.

Answer (score 7):

Case C is in 6/8 so, as you say, the strong beat is the first of each three. Your example is written as if it's a 3/4 bar. Strictly speaking, it should be written:
[image]

6/8 bars are counted in two groups of three quavers (eighth notes). I've marked the main beats 1 and (1) and you should be tapping your foot on those, even though there is no note on the second one '(1)'.

The first four notes are accented as Aaron described in his first example, and the last two are semi-strong.

Composers have exploited the similarity between 6/8 bars and 3/4 ones for centuries. You could read about this - *hemiola*, as it's called - [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiola). Or just listen to Ginastera's [Malambo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y36xmzYpujc&t=184s), the 4th movement of his Estancia Suite.

Comment: ...or listen to 'America'...

Comment: @Tim I thought it would make a change!

Comment: Still, for someone who is learning about the phenomenon, it is perhaps not so familiar as to the rest of us!  America -  https://youtu.be/_e2igZexpMs?t=56

Answer (score 0):

6/8 would be S,W,W,M,W,W
Where S=strong, W=week, M=medium