# Question about beats and their inheritance of accents on the rhythm

Tags: theory, beats, meter, accent

I see that I've created a lot of confusion with my original question, so I have decided to send the author of "How to read Music in 30 Days, English 2022 Ed." a detailed question that should clearly state my concern.

As it contains quite a lot of text and sketches, these are now attached in handwritten form (I hope this doesn't lead to any forum rules being broken):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142205/discussion-on-question-by-iwab-question-about-beats-and-their-inheritance-of-acc).

Answer (score 9):

NOTE: Most of this answer makes less sense than it used to because the asker has almost completely re-written the question. The image at the bottom of this answer is the most current content here. I'm leaving the rest in case it is helpful in other ways and/or the question is reverted or re-edited in some way.

---

**Neither 1 nor 2 is correct, but 1 is definitely wrong, while 2 is close but missing some details.**

I’ve been taught, and I hear in almost all music, the following (q means quaver or 1/8 note):

**Q** q Q q Q q | **Q** q Q q Q q |

The first quaver is the strongest, and then the quavers that fall on beats 2 and 3 are weaker, but they are stronger than the quavers that make up the second half of each beat.

The emphasis may be very very slight, but to my ears it’s definitely there. A similar pattern exists in all time signatures, as in there’s a hierarchy of emphasis where the first beat gets the most and subdivisions usually have slightly less strength as the note values get smaller.

---

Regarding the 2/4 example, it would be similar to 3/4 but one beat shorter:

**Q** q Q q | **Q** q Q q

4/4 time can have a very slight extra emphasis on beat three:

**Q** q Q q *Q* q Q q | **Q** q Q q *Q* q Q q

---

Your last diagrams corrected:

[image]

Note that the big **S** at the start of the first beat is meant to indicate a stronger accent than the smaller s-es.

One other thought I've had: The strength of accents for a measure of music is different when the music in that measure is different - even with the same time signature. The accents I've written into the image above only apply as I've written them when the measure is filled with quavers. If other note values appear in a measure, then the accents are adjusted accordingly. It wouldn't be feasible to lay out here all of the accent patterns for all of the possible rhythms in a measure.

Comment: @It'sHEDLEY Perhaps. But neither 1 nor 2 is correct.

Comment: The question is rather ambiguous (to some), but from what you say, surely no. 2 is way more correct than no. 1. And the example OP shows is for something somewhat different. As in there is nowhere in it where two consecutive notes could be at the beginning of a bar. Or have I missed something?

Comment: @Tim I don’t understand your comment. Two consecutive notes at the beginning of a bar? Do you mean two quavers in the first beat? Because that’s clearly in the asker’s examples.

Comment: @ToddWilcox based on It'sHedley's anwere your edit confused me more. I thought that if stated "accent on 1. Beat. per measure" in 2-4 it's Beat1 so Q q and then Beat2 so q q. You wrote the quaver >rhythm< as if it was a 4-4 >pulse<.

Comment: @iwab I can’t quite decipher your comment. My answer is not meant to be compatible with the other answers. If it seems like it contradicts another answer, then that’s intentional. Beyond that, what I’m trying to communicate is that in music there are **multiple levels of accent**. The most accented is the very first part of the first beat of each measure, and there are other softer accents in other parts of a measure. Also I wonder if I’m not clear on what you mean by “pulse”. If the meter is 3/4 or 4/4 or 2/4 then there are accent patterns for their meters. “Pulse” is not relevant, AFAIK

Comment: @iwab If you’re struggling with the level of detail in my answer and want to just know whether you should play more like 1 or 2 in your question, then **2 is almost correct and 1 is not**. You shouldn’t play like 1 in any case. If you play like 2 then that’s going to be at least acceptable in most cases but not ideal.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I know that there are multiple ways, in a two-four >beat< it's S w| S w, in a three-four it's S w w| S w w and in a four four it's S w s w| S w s w, but all those examples are for the pulse (the underlying, steady throb that can be felt in music, "beat" sometimes refer to one instance of it). Now we can build >rhythm< above the pulse (that's what sheets show) and if we state we have a 3/4 >pulse< and now build a rhythm with 1/8 notes on top of that I wanted to know how the defined accent from >beat< goes over to the >Rhythm< that's actually played.

Comment: @iwab If you haven't already, take a look at the other linked posts (in the "linked posts" list as well as linked in my comments). In particular, [Rhythmic/Metric Stress Patterns](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/103975/70803) addresses the question in your most recent comment to ToddWilcox.

Comment: @iwab I tried to make it very clear in my answer how the quavers work. Quavers on the beat have the exact same emphasis as crotchets on the beat. Quavers off the beat (on the “and” of a beat) have less emphasis than anything else - they are the weakest. Including the off-beat quaver during beat one.

Comment: @ToddWilcox oooh, I always thought that accent is strictly tied to the pulse and I have somehow "translate" it to the rhythm, because my book always state that "beats" have accents.

Comment: @iwab Does your book also state that "pulses" and "beats" are the same thing? I don't understand exactly what you're trying to say with "pulse" and where you got that term. Beats do have accents. Also subdivisions of beats have accents. And subdivisions of those subdivisions also have accents. But you only apply a stronger or weaker feel to a **note** that **starts** on a beat or subdivision. If you're holding a note you don't vary the accent as you hold it. And if you don't play any notes during a beat or subdivision, then those stronger or weaker feelings are bypassed and ignored.

Comment: @ToddWilcox it provides following definition: "Pulse" - The Pulse is the constant beat underlying the music. It is steady and consistent. The pulse is assigned a note value so that it becomes a quarter note beat, or a... . "Beat" - this term has several but related uses. It's often another word for pulse, but can also refer to one instance of it (that is, one pulsation)

Answer (score 4):

The word "beat" has different meanings depending on context. "Beat" sometimes refers to an entire time duration, but it also can mean the beginning of such a duration.

- "A quarter-note gets one beat" means a quarter note lasts one unit of time.
- "Beat one gets the accent" means that the onset of the first time duration is stressed in comparison to the beginnings of other durations.

---

When speaking of meter, the metrical emphasis is presumed to apply only to the note occurring at the onset of the first beat.

- In a first beat of two quavers, only the first quaver would receive emphasis.
- In a first beat comprising a semiquaver rest followed by three semiquavers, none of the notes would receive emphasis.
- In a first beat in which a crotchet is tied over from the previous measure, there is no emphasis.

When one says that a particular beat gets an emphasis, the emphasis applies to the note at the onset of that beat, not to all notes comprising the duration of that beat.

Comment: Would the last image I added be therefore correct?

Comment: @iwab Yes, with the additional detail that beat two would be weaker than beat one, but stronger than the second quavers of each beat. Something like `S w s w | S w s w`. See also [Where the accent should be when the beat is made up of different notes](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/103591/70803) and [How simple time and compound time signatures change the rhythm](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/103586/70803).

Comment: @iwab Another way to say it (which is covered in the answers to the posts linked above) is that each beat has its relative strength, and each part of a beat also has a relative strength. Four quavers in 2/4 time will receive an accent pattern very similar to four crotchets in 4/4 time. Another post that might help: [Rhythmic/Metric Stress Patterns](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/103975/70803).

Comment: I think your answers somehow helped me, but your comment confused me a little. In my handwritten image the buttom should be the pulse consisting of two beats per measure and the top is the rhythm build on top of that pulse. If you tell me that my rhythm should actually be S w s w that somehow contradicts your original answere. For the rhythm accent S w s w I would need a beat of 4/8.

Comment: @iwab Yes, 2/4 and 4/8 are essentially identical in the way the eighth notes are emphasized. In x/4 time, in any pairing of two eighth notes in a single beat, the first of the pair is stronger. Your hand-written diagram suggests that the two eighth notes comprising beat 2 are of equal emphasis. The first eighth note of beat two is stronger than the second eighth note of beat two, and the first eighth note of beat one is stronger than the first eighth note of beat two.

Comment: Oh ok that's interesting. Based on your definition I thought it's "If the Beat is 4/X than emphasize the first Note of Beat1 and Beat3 per Measure." But with 2/4 I only have two beats with S w, so I thought it can only be the first note emphasized of beat 1 and since beat2 isn't emphasized at all then also not note 1 from beat 2

Comment: @iwab note1 from beat2 is emphasized in comparison to note2 from beat2. Your book might have been more clear to have said "the onset of beat1 contains the *primary* stress within the measure."

Comment: @iwab 2/4 and 4/8 are effectively identical, given four eighth notes in one measure. For this reason, 4/8 is rarely used.

Answer (score 2):

This all seems very confused, and I'm not sure the answers so far are helping to clarify… so let's take a different approach.

Let's start with a clock, tick-tocking in time.
Tick is always stronger than tock, so in 2/4 time, your clock would simply be going

**Tick** tock **Tick** tock

In 3/4 time it would go

**Tick** tock tock **Tick** tock tock

OK, so we don't have a real clock any more, but you can still imagine this.

If we add quavers, then we could use this instead - you can say this out loud to help. Keep your main tick tock at the same speed, but add a new sound in between.

**Tick** a tock a tock a **Tick** a tock a tock a

As we sub-divide away from our strong **Tick** each new element becomes weaker than the last.

Comment: Yes, that artificial "a" is just an supportive element to evenly put 2 Quavers in one "Tock", so one in [Tock1; Tock1.5[ and the other in [Tock1.5; Tock2[. But when those 2 Quavers belong to Tock1 then I don't understand why the accent ("..") isn't an inherited trait for both: "Tick"("Quaver", Quaver) and not Tick"("Quaver", "Quaver") how I thought..

Comment: "Why?" Who knows, but it's not. Humans just don't tick that way ;) Incidentally, did you know most clocks don't actually go 'tick tock' at all, they just go 'tick' - the rest is human perception, forcing things into patterns.

Comment: that's mostly true but in theoretical interpretations and logic it's natural that if a parent element have a specific trait (here Beat1), then it's children elements have it also (here the 2 Quavers).

Comment: "theoretical interpretations and logic" of what? You're really over-thinking this & trying to apply some kind of mathematical species logic to something that simply doesn't use the same values. I cannot say it any clearer than 'each sub-division is weaker than the last'.

Comment: I thought there must be some degree of logic behind the framework of musical notation, how would I know that it's mostly the first note per beat per measure that's accented if it's just statet that Beat1 is accented? Then somebody had to tell me that the trait of Beat1 just goes over to the first element.

Comment: There is a degree of logic, it's just not the one you seem to be trying to apply. Best thing would be to go off & actually **listen** to some music structured in this way & hear it for yourself. You really cannot argue this out on any non-musical logic basis, you have to accept from other musicians that this is how it works in practise. "Belonging to the mathematical group which comprises beat 1" is not the way this works. 'Beat 1' is over & done with as soon as you have a new note to play, wherever it might be.

Comment: @iwab - the tick a (or tock a) often isn't even even. It could be 2/3 tick and 1/3 a, or 3/4 tick and 1/4 a, just to make you aware. BUT - the 1st part of any bar is normally the emphasised part, otherwise we wouldn't know where the bar lines belong, and not be able to give a time signature to the music.

Comment: @Tim - I was trying to simplify as much as possible, as the OP seems to really have hold of the wrong end of the stick here.

Comment: I'm darned sure you're right - hence my vtc. Even after my seemingly futile effort to answer the original question!

Comment: @Tim (at)Tetsujin I think I've got it, I've added an second example in my question that might make it more clear :-)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are assuming accent is only a matter of dynamics, that accent is achieved by loudness. The details of your post all look to me like "how much of the duration of the first beat should I play louder than all the rest."

The problem with that is the accent of beat one is more conceptual that just dynamics. You could play an entire phrase of music with a crescendo without undermining the idea of beat one is accented. Even more emphatically you could have *rests* on beat one, silence, and still maintain the beat one accent. Rhythmic concepts like *syncopation* and *hemiola* also contradict the accented beat one idea. But on "day 4" we don't want to get ahead of ourselves.

The passage of the book describes accent at a very basic level. I don't know how the rest of the book covers the topic, but I assume it doesn't go into issues of beat subdivisions and meter, or else you would not have asked this question.

Re-read that page carefully. The author does not say accent is only achieved by playing a beat strongly. The author does not say beat one is always accented.

I would look at that passage of the book like this. If you had some music which was only quarter notes with no pitch changes (that is essential what the notation shows) the obvious way to play that and achieve some sense of an accented beat one (which would then define a conceptual bar line) is to apply a (dynamic) accent on some of those notes at a regular period.

That book is probably a "fundamentals of music" type text so it isn't going to get into a deep discussion of meter. It just wants to introduce the idea of how to count beats, beat grouping, and the bar line. Do not read it too literally and apply it to performance dynamics.

> How are notes weighted if the accent is on first beat?

They are weighted, dynamically accented, any way you like.

This part of the book is not trying to explain that.

I agree with Tim's answer that the onset, the very first moment, of beat one is what is accented. In that sense your example of two quavers on beat one would put a dynamic accent on the first quaver but not the second. I've never read a performance rule of thumb that was so prescriptive. It's just a literal misapplication of a metrical concept to the art of performance.

I think one practical thing should be mentioned about beat one and how its accent is typically and most obviously manifest in music. The accent of beat one is what defines the bar line and two very important things are organized around the bar line: phrase starting and ending, and chord changes. Those are structural elements rather than dynamic elements.

> I've started learning music theory and have a question

It's good to have questions and use them to probe a text. But if you're working with *Ellul, How to Read Music in 30 Days: Music Theory for Beginners*, I would try writing those questions down and set them aside so you can work through the 30 days without getting side tracked. It will be a lot to absorb and you probably want it to flow into your mind unrestricted by questions. At least for that first "30 days." Get it in first, then question it in a second phase. Some questions may be answered within the text but not until you put all the pieces together. Other questions may lead you to other texts. And don't forget that real scores and great performance recordings are often the best textbooks. Look for answers from the great musicians.

Answer (score 1):

A beat doesn't really have a duration value, it's more like a moment in time.

Consider an analogy with a clock:  *At what time is it noon?*
If you are just looking at just the hours, you could kinda (somewhat clumsily) say that "noon is an hour long".  Whereas if you are counting minutes you might think of it as only a minute long (with 11:59 being *before* noon, and being 12:01 being *after* noon).  But you could also count seconds ... etc.
Really, noon is just an instantaneous moment; without any duration value at all (a single point).
(But, whatever units you are counting, surely you wouldn't say that 12:00 and 12:30 are both "at noon", would you?)

Similarly, it's more precise to say that beats don't really have durations, instead consecutive beats are *separated* by a duration value.

---

Generally, the first beat of the bar has the strongest accent, other beats get some kind of medium accent, and any other moment get a weak accent.
Further subdivisions (semiquavers) would introduce more weak/weaker moments in the gaps.

#### A few simple examples

(using `S` for strong, `M` for medium, and `w` for weak)

A bar of 3/4 filled with crotchets:

```
1   2   3   |
S   M   M   |
```

And now filled with quavers:

```
1 & 2 & 3 & |
S w M w M w |
```

A bar of 2/4 filled with crotchets:

```
1   2   |
S   M   |
```

And now filled with quavers:

```
1 & 2 & |
S w M w |
```

---

So, your option 2 is good, but it'd be even better if you used a mix of "Quaver"s and "quaver"s, to show the difference between the medium and the weak:

- **Quaver** - quaver - Quaver - quaver - Quaver - quaver

Comment: "A beat doesn't really have a duration value, it's more like a moment in time." I started a discussion about this yesterday: https://www.reddit.com/r/musictheory/comments/10bq3y7/how_would_i_even_play_2_notes_in_one_beat/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=android_app&utm_name=androidcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button

Comment: Excerpt: "Yes, a beat takes up time."
"Music is continuous in time, each "beat" is the slice of time between the beginning of the beat, and the beginning of the next beat."
"A beat is a length of time. Not a singular point." So I concluded the mathematical definition where a beat starts and ends must be the half open time interval "[Beat_x; Beat_x+1["

Comment: @iwab Consider a conductor's baton: it marks the beats with continuous motion, it turns sharply on the beat moment; it doesn't stop at any point and wait for the "beat" to end before moving to the next beat, does it?

Comment: that might be true but doesn't provide me the idea you want to make clear.

Comment: I find your answer genuinely confusing. While we frequently refer to "beat X" to mean "the beginning of beat X", it's not true that beats don't have duration. The whole point of a beat is that it has duration — that it divides time into discrete units.

Comment: It's an interesting concept, but I'll need time to consider.

Comment: @It's…HEDLEY  
I suppose the term "beat" is overloaded with only slightly different meanings.  
For we do say the second quaver in the bar occurs *on* the "&" *of* beat 1,  
but a note played at this time certainly isn't "*on* the beat".

Answer (score -1):

It's not the *beat* that's stressed as much as the first sound made in each bar. So, the 1st quaver, or even semiquaver, is the most stressed note in any bar. That's how we can determine where the beginning of each bar is, thus what the time signature will be.

EDIT: this answer is based on the *question*, which only gives the choice of stress between the 1st quaver, or the 1st **two** quavers. The comments (thus dvs) are presumably based on what else was read into its wording. It's pretty obvious that if there's no note on beat 1 there can't be emphasis there, but that's not the premise of the question, in fact, it's really a different question. Think on it!

Comment: Oh ok, so is the definition provided by "How to Read Music in 30 Days by Ellul" wrong? (I've added a picture in my question)

Comment: @iwab It's not wrong, it's just a confusing use of language. The word "beat" is used both to refer to the entire duration and the moment at which the duration begins. Here it refers to the moment at which the duration begins.

Comment: Sorry, Tim, but this is not worded properly. What if the first note in the bar doesn't come at 1? Or what if 1 is syncopated?

Comment: @ojs - that's immaterial to the question. Which only concerns the first  or first and second quaver in the particular bar. Please read the question!

Comment: @user1079505 - the 1st note does indeed come on the 1st beat, please read the question!